# How to permanently disable the Do Not Disturb focus setting on a Mac? (disable the ability to turn it on)

Tags: mac, notifications, system-settings, focus

How can I remove the ability to enable the Do Not Disturb focus on a Mac?

I've had a number of times where I inadvertently, unknowingly enabled the Do Not Disturb focus with the F6 key, and didn't realize it until hours or days later.  I don't ever want to be able to do that.

macOS: Ventura 13.4.1

Comment: I'm not aware of F6 being a default binding for Do Not Disturb; can you go to [Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcCAU.png) and make sure nothing is set as a shortcut there?

Comment: Check your Notification and Focus setting for customized set up

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about F6 it must be custom (by you) set, but go to the settings and see the set up. As you can see I have nothing there.

Since it is a part of the OS it cannot be disabled: you can only create/change settings. If there is nothing set, it is effectively disabled.

[image: settings]